# problem to launch gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hi , i have Ubuntu 12.04 and i begin to find my empty_world.launch file in my ROS package
i found it in :
fuerte /stacks / simulator_gazebo / gazebo_worlds / launch / empty_world.launch
begin to launch gazebo using this command on the Terminal :
$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
I get back this long reply !! and i don't know what is the problem exactly !!  :**

```
... logging to /home/salma/.ros/log/bad9db3a-0b2a-11e2-9b14-00e04c4d0e3f/roslaunch-salma-G31M-S2L-2792.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://salma-G31M-S2L:46927/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo/gui)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [2808]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to bad9db3a-0b2a-11e2-9b14-00e04c4d0e3f
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [2821]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [2824]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [2831]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Msg Waiting for master[ INFO] [1349028902.956390978]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...


Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1349028905.693671950]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
[ INFO] [1349028912.404487554, 0.057000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1349028912.760845061, 1.894000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  2834 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 2831, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/salma/.ros/log/bad9db3a-0b2a-11e2-9b14-00e04c4d0e3f/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/salma/.ros/log/bad9db3a-0b2a-11e2-9b14-00e04c4d0e3f/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44818/problem-to-launch-gazebo/) by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-09-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) on 2012-09-30**:
could be a graphics card related issue.
Can you take a look at this page (http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Troubleshooting) and fill in some more details as mentioned by the second half of the wiki here? Thanks.

**Comment by [muin028](https://answers.ros.org/users/2804/muin028/) on 2012-10-12**:
I am also getting the same kind of problem.My OS is----ubuntu 10.04 LTS(32bit deb),Graphics card and graphics card driver version:---00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GME965/GLE960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
and rosbuild_make_distribution(1.6.16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@muin028:
Gazebo/OGRE is very sensitive regarding graphics cards and very rarely (if at all?) works with integrated graphics controllers. For Gazebo your best bet is probably an NVIDIA graphics card - I've had a laptop with an ATI card that worked but it's more of a gamble than using NVIDA I think (at least 3 years ago when I had my ATI laptop it was).

You can also check OGRE's hardware requirements, but I think you should be good with any modern dedicated graphics card: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Hardware

Btw there's a new website for Gazebo related questions: http://answers.gazebosim.org/

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.ros.org/users/400/thomask/) with karma: 360 on 2012-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0